# Fastest way to select several inserted rows

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a table in a database which stores items. Each item has a unique ID, which the DB generates upon insertion (auto-increment).
A user may perform a specific task that will add X items to the database, however my program (C++ server application using MySQL connector) should return the IDs that the database generated right away. For example, if I add 6 items, the server must return 6 new unique IDs to the client.
What is the fastest/cleanest way to do such thing? So far I have been doing `INSERT` followed by `SELECT` for each new item OR `INSERT` followed by `last_insert_id`, however if there are 50 items to add it will take a few seconds at least which is not good at all for user experience.

```
sql_task.query("INSERT INTO `ItemDB` (`ItemName`, `Type`, `Time`) VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d')", strName.c_str(), uiType, uiTime);
```

Getting the ID:

```
uint64_t item_id { sql_task.last_id() }; //This calls mysql_insert_id
```

Comment: please add some code please

Comment: Alright, I added some code. It all works fine, but it's not fast at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to rethink your design slightly. Let's use the analogy of a sales order. With a sales order (or invoice #) the user gets an invoice number (auto_incr) as well as multiple line item numbers (also auto_inc).

The sales order and all of the line items are selected for insert (from the GUI) and the inserts are performed. First, the sales order row is inserted and its id is saved in a variable for subsequent calls to insert the line items. But the line items are then just inserted without immediate return of their auto_inc id values. The application is merely returned the sales order number in the end. How your app uses that sales order number in subsequent calls is up to you. But it does not need to be immediate to retrieve all the X or 50 rows at once, as it has the sales order number iced and saved somewhere. Let's call that sales order number XYZ.

When you actually need the information, an example call could look like

```
select lineItemId 
from lineItems 
where salesOrderNumber=XYZ 
order by lineItemId
```

---

You need to remember that in a multi-user system that there is no guarantee of receiving a contiguous block of numbers. Nor should it matter to you, as they are all attached appropriately with the correct sales order number.

Again, the above is just an analogy, used for illustration purposes.

Comment: That analogy was great, thanks! Actually, it is not even my design, since I'm trying to reproduce a server's behavior but that part was confusing. A user can buy a couple items at once, and the server will add them to the DB and then return a unique ID to the client for each item bought. They do it very fast, so I was wondering if there was something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a common but hard to solve problem. Unsure for mysql, but PostreSQL uses *sequences* to generate automatic ids. Inserting frameworks (object relationnal mappers) use that when they expect to insert many values: they query directly the sequence for a bunch of IDs and then insert new rows using those already known IDs. That way, no need for an additional query after each insert to get the ID.

The downside is that the relation ID - insertion time can be non monotonic when different writers intermix their inserts. It is not a problem for the database, but some (poorly written?) program could expect it is.

Answer (score -1):

As you ID is autoincremental, you can do only two `SELECT` queries - before and after `INSERT` queries:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'dbTable' AND table_schema = DATABASE();
--
-- INSERT INTO dbTable... (one or many, does not matter);
--
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lastID;
```

This will give you the siquence between first and last inserted IDs. Then you can easily calculate how many they are.

Comment: It is not that easy. Concurrent session can increment insert ID too. And of course multi-master clusters of MySQL doesn't increment by 1.

Comment: I agree with rkosegi since I'm also worried about that too. If I have an external tool that can add items to that same table and I happen to add items at the same time, the client may get some IDs that are different.

Comment: @rkosegi in general yes, you are right, but it depends. Since InnoDB performs a lock during the insert, other inserts must wait for the insert to finish the transaction (if there a such). Everything is depends from implementation.

Comment: @mitkosoft : so if it depends on implementation, how you can make assumptions about it in application code?

Comment: @rkosegi, almost each soluition here in SO is based on given input and description, same is mine. As didn't see into the description any additional dependencies and constraints, I'm proposing this approach instead of calling the db after each (non-concurrent by the description) insert.

Comment: For me, this sounds like proposing something which can lead into hard-to-debug/sometimes reproducible problems.

Comment: feel free to propose better and most reliable solution at anytime.